# Optimize a request who use some select inside

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an SQL request who never finish because it take too much time so i try to optimize it but i don't find anyway for the moment.

My request is this one :

```
SELECT id ,field1 
FROM table1
WHERE id NOT IN(
    SELECT id_table1 FROM table2 WHERE id_table1 IS NOT NULL
) 
AND( 
    id IN(
        SELECT id_table1 FROM table3 GROUP BY id_table1
    ) 
    OR id IN(
        SELECT id_table1 FROM table4 GROUP BY id_table1
    )
) 
ORDER BY field1
```

The problem come from the `OR` i think because when i replace by `AND` it finish in few seconds.

Comment: try to move OR statement in UNION , i guess it will help

Comment: what are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the tables using  explicit cartesian joins.

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.field1 
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id_table1
INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON t1.id = t3.id_table1
INNER JOIN table4 t4 ON t1.id = t4.id_table1
WHERE t1.id != t2.id_table1 
AND t1.id = t3.id_table1  
OR t1.id = t4.id_table1
ORDER BY t1.field1
```

Or use implicit cartesian joins using Exists/Not Exists

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.field1 
FROM table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM table2 t2
                  WHERE t1.id = t2.id_table1 
                  AND t2.id_table1 IS NOT NULL)
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
            FROM table3 t3 
            WHERE t1.id = t3.id_table1) 
OR EXISTS (SELECT 1
           FROM table4 t4
           WHERE t1.id = t4.id_table1);
```

Comment: I believe LEFT JOIN should be used instead of INNER JOIN. A "NOT IN" is typically a LEFT JOIN ... WHERE id IS NULL.

Comment: Ah ok possibly, i was using an inner to eliminate the need for the where xxx is null

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
SELECT id ,field1 
FROM table1
WHERE id NOT IN(
    SELECT id_table1 FROM table2 WHERE id_table1 IS NOT NULL
) 
AND( 
    id IN(
        (SELECT id_table1 FROM table3 GROUP BY id_table1)
Union all

            (SELECT id_table1 FROM table4 GROUP BY id_table1)

) 
ORDER BY field1
```

Comment: I cannot see what problem this solution is supposed to solve

Comment: Strawberry, I dont know what data base he is using, but he said when he changed the Or to And it came back quickly.

Comment: I think you're missing the point. This is not an efficient way of joining tables.

Comment: I think that the best way to improve it its to know what can of data base he is using... And again, if he changed the or to and, then it might help.

Comment: You're entitled to think that. i think you're mistaken.